# Get Sessions in VB.net

Tags: php, vb.net, session

If I have two files, one in PHP and one in VB.net, how could I get the two to work together?

***user.php***

```
echo $_SESSION['user'];
```

***and on the VB.net I have this***

```
Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://mywebsite.com/user.php")
```

I would like the vb.net sourceString to be the session echoed in PHP.
Is there another way to do this, or could I make the VB code download the string with their default browser so the sessions would be set?

Comment: `echo json_encode($_SESSION);` and then parse in VB?  But it would be the session for the VB script so it needs to accept and offer cookies.

Comment: see JWT https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet